# Values lost when form made invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a simple wizard. I created one static class for holding my forms:

```
    namespace LABEL_AUTOMATION
    {
        static class ProjectHelper
        {
            public static Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            public static Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        }

    }
```

and for form1's next button I am having the following code:

```
 private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        ProjectHelper.frm2.Visible = true;
    }
```

and similar logic for form2's back button:

```
private void buttonPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    ProjectHelper.frm1.Visible = true;
}
```

The problem is that when I move between the forms, the values of the controls like textbox gets cleared.

How to correct it ?

Also, I am using the form's visible changed event to execute the code when the user switches between forms. But, the event gets fired before the form gets visible. Any other event that I can use ?

**EDIT:** I actually didnt change the Program.cs file which was actually creating and running a seperate instance of Form1.  So I changed my code to:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ProjectHelper.frm1.Show();
}
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'LABEL_AUTOMATION.ProjectHelper' threw an exception.
```

Comment: do you see what exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are showing/hiding instances of your forms which are not in `ProjectHelper` class.

You should at Main do

```
ProjectHelper.frm1.Show();
```

or

```
ProjectHelper.frm2.Show();
```

Comment: You are exactly right ! I changed the as suggested by you but its showing me an error. Please see my update in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem of the clearing controls, I would create a simple POCO class to hold the data, and use databinding to bind the controls to the POCO class instance. This way, all your entered data on the forms is saved in the POCO class automatically, and when a form is shown again, the values are there again.

About your visible-changed-event - one option is to create your own event, and fire that in the forms. You can then create a base class which automates the firing of the event. What exactly are you doing in this visible-changed-eventhandler?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this issue, but i think, that you can save all yourvalues in some variables before you make it invisible and load this settings when your form is visible again

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the values in a external class or you fill the values in both formelements when the value is changing.

You can use the event `TextChanged` or `ValueChanged` in the controlelement and then you set the value in the other form.
Or with a external class, you set the value in there, and every time you switch, you have to reload the values from the external class.

**HINT**: I wouldn't use more then one form. Just use only one form and some panels and set them visible or invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make one form, and make an `UserControl` for each step in your wizard. Your form then manages the visibility of the panels and can handle (or fire) events.

This way you do not need statics and have full control over the life of; and data in the wizard steps.

Second, create a custom class (data holder) for each wizard step, and use windows forms databinding for databinding the UI controls (and validation) to your data holder. This way, you do not need event handling on the wizard step to save your data, and the wizard itself will become a simple view.